# Multiple left outer joins on Hive

Tags: hive, hiveql

In Hive, I have two tables as shown below:

`SELECT * FROM p_test;
OK
p_test.id       p_test.age
01      1
02      2
01      10
02      11
Time taken: 0.07 seconds, Fetched: 4 row(s)`

`SELECT * FROM p_test2;
OK
p_test2.id      p_test2.height
02      172
01      170
Time taken: 0.053 seconds, Fetched: 2 row(s)`

I'm supposed to get the age differences between the same user in the p_test table. Hence, I run HiveQL via **row_number** function as following:

`SELECT *
FROM 
    (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(partition by id order by age asc) rn FROM p_test) t1
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(partition by id order by age asc) rn FROM p_test) t2
ON t2.id=t1.id AND t1.rn=(t2.rn+1)
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT * FROM p_test2) t_2
ON t_2.id = t1.id;`

The result of it is :

`t1.id   t1.age  t1.rn   t2.id   t2.age  t2.rn   t_2.id  t_2.height
01      1       1       NULL    NULL    NULL    01      170
01      10      2       01      1       1       01      170
02      11      1       NULL    NULL    NULL    02      172
02      2       2       02      11      1       02      172
Time taken: 60.773 seconds, Fetched: 4 row(s)`

It is all ok so far. However, If I move the condition which left joins table **t1** and table **t2** shown above to the last line as shown below:

`SELECT *
FROM 
    (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(partition by id order by age asc) rn FROM p_test) t1
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(partition by id order by age asc) rn FROM p_test) t2
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT * FROM p_test2) t_2
ON t_2.id = t1.id
AND t2.id=t1.id AND t1.rn=(t2.rn+1);`

I got the unexpected result as following:

`t1.id   t1.age  t1.rn   t2.id   t2.age  t2.rn   t_2.id  t_2.height
01      1       1       01      1       1       NULL    NULL
01      1       1       01      10      2       NULL    NULL
01      1       1       02      11      1       NULL    NULL
01      1       1       02      2       2       NULL    NULL
01      10      2       01      1       1       01      170
01      10      2       01      10      2       NULL    NULL
01      10      2       02      11      1       NULL    NULL
01      10      2       02      2       2       NULL    NULL
02      11      1       01      1       1       NULL    NULL
02      11      1       01      10      2       NULL    NULL
02      11      1       02      11      1       NULL    NULL
02      11      1       02      2       2       NULL    NULL
02      2       2       01      1       1       NULL    NULL
02      2       2       01      10      2       NULL    NULL
02      2       2       02      11      1       02      172
02      2       2       02      2       2       NULL    NULL`

It seems that the condition which I move to the last line doesn't work anymore. It bothers me for a long time. Do hope I can hear any valuable answers, thx for anyone who provides me with answers in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your second query `LEFT JOIN` with t2 without ON condition is transformed to `CROSS JOIN`. This is why you have duplication. For id=01 you have two rows in subquery t1 and 2 rows in t2 initially, this CROSS join gives you 2x2=4 rows.

And the ON condition works, but it is applied only to the last LEFT join with t_2 subquery, this condition is being checked only to determine which rows to join in the last join, not all joins, it does not affect first CROSS JOIN (LEFT JOIN without ON condition) at all.

Every join should have it's own ON condition, except cross joins.

See also this answer about joins without ON condition behavior: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46843832/2700344

BTW you can do the same without t2 join at all using lag or lead analytic functions for calculating values ordered by age.

Like this:

`lag(height)  over(partition by id order by age)` -- to get previous height

Comment: Thx so much for your valuable answer, it does help me a lot. The last question, in the second query, if I change `LEFT JOIN` to `JOIN`, it turns out that the condition locates in the last line applied to t2 causing `inner join` instead of `cross join`. As it only returns 2 rows instead of 16 rows as shown above. Do you have any ideas about this?

Comment: **HQL**:      `SELECT *
FROM 
    (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(partition by id order by age asc) rn FROM p_test) t1
JOIN
    (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(partition by id order by age asc) rn FROM p_test) t2
JOIN
    (SELECT * FROM p_test2) t_2
ON t_2.id = t1.id
AND t2.id=t1.id AND t1.rn=(t2.rn+1);`

Comment: **Result**:     t1.id   t1.age  t1.rn   t2.id   t2.age  t2.rn   t_2.id  t_2.height
01      10      2       01      1       1       01      170
02      2       2       02      11      1       02      172
Time taken: 91.713 seconds, Fetched: 2 row(s)

Comment: @AdamBacon JOIN is INNER by default if not specified.Also join without condition is CROSS, if condition is in where it filters rows and finally it works as inner because does not allows nulls. Add OR t2.rn is NULL and it should work as LEFT join