# Not able to reference Hive date variable in later set statements

Tags: variables, hive

I am trying to store a date into hive variable but not able to use it later.

```
hive> select to_date(date_sub(last_day(FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(),'yyyy-MM-dd')),1));
OK
2019-07-30

set my_date=select to_date(date_sub(last_day(FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(),'yyyy-MM-dd')),1));
```

now I want to extract year and month out of my_date but it's not working.

```
hive> select date_format('${hiveconf:my_date}','yyyy-MM');
FAILED: ParseException line 1:85 missing ) at 'yyyy' near 'yyyy'
line 1:89 missing EOF at '-' near 'yyyy'
```

below statement is working:

```
hive> select date_format('2019-07-30','yyyy-MM');
OK
2019-07
```

Not sure what's happening. How can I refer to my_date variable and store year & month in another set of variable in hive.

```
set year_month_date = select date_format('${hiveconf:my_date}','yyyy-MM');
```

Comment: Unfortunately, Hive variables substitution does not work in such way. It is simple substitution without calculation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hive variable substitution is simple text replacement. This statement:

`set my_date=select to_date(date_sub(last_day(FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(),'yyyy-MM-dd')),1));` will assign string  `'select to_date(date_sub(last_day(FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(),'yyyy-MM-dd')),1))'` to the variable `my_date`. Hive does not calculate variables unfortunately. And your final statement will be resolved as

```
select date_format('select to_date(date_sub(last_day(FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(),'yyyy-MM-dd')),1))','yyyy-MM');
```

And this is incorrect select statement.

You can calculate the variable in the separate script and pass it to another script using shell, like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37821218/2700344). See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/56450129/2700344

You can print variable inside the Hive script using shell echo command:

```
! echo my_date contains '${hiveconf:my_date}';
```

Also do not use FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(),'yyyy-MM-dd'). Use current_date() instead, see this answer for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41140298/2700344.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was banging my head over this. ☺️. It helped me a lot